# how to do a join query for huge tables?

Tags: mysql

hopefully somebody can help me with this query. I need to list all 200 records from `ngr_titles` below, joined with their most recent related record  from `ngr_monitordata`. The foreign key in ngr_monitordata is called `titleid` and the most recent should be the higher `when_posted` value for each title.
The problem is that `ngr_monitordata` contains millions of records and is increasing every second.

This is the query I used but it takes 14 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM ngr_titles
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT titleid, MAX(when_posted) FROM ngr_monitordata GROUP BY titleid) tmp1
ON ngr_titles.id= tmp1.titleid;
```

What would be the best approach?

Tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `ngr_titles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `drop_min` int(11) NOT NULL default '50',
  `warn_pcnt` float(5,1) NOT NULL default '15.0',
  `crit_pcnt` float(5,1) NOT NULL default '25.0',
  `deviations` float(5,1) NOT NULL default '2.0',
  `addlobby` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `graph_url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `lastchecked` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `last_exception` int(11) default NULL,
  `state` enum('ok','warning','critical') default NULL,
  `trend` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `short_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `historical` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `cacti_url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `ngr_monitordata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `titleid` int(11) default NULL,
  `when_posted` int(11) default NULL,
  `games_completed` int(11) default NULL,
  `games_created` int(11) default NULL,
  `games_in_progress` int(11) default NULL,
  `games_in_progress_gps` int(11) default NULL,
  `users_in_games` int(11) default NULL,
  `users_in_games_gps` int(11) default NULL,
  `users_in_lobby` int(11) default NULL,
  `users_in_passive` int(11) default NULL,
  `users_in_rooms` int(11) default NULL,
  `rooms` int(11) default NULL,
  `state` enum('ok','warning','critical','unknown') NOT NULL default 'ok',
  `user_drop` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `retries` int(8) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `whowhenidx` (`titleid`,`when_posted`),
  KEY `whenidx` (`when_posted`),
  KEY `titleidx` (`titleid`),
  KEY `stateidx` (`state`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=120512615 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM 
    ngr_titles t 
INNER JOIN 
ngr_monitordata m
    ON 
t.id = m.titleid 
    AND 
m.when_posted = (SELECT MAX(when_posted) FROM ngr_monitordata WHERE titleid = t.id)
```

Quick solution, it should work although I wrote it in haste. If it were me, I'd normalize the data slightly to reduce the overhead from aggregate function and subquery.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. The query you suggested doesn't return all the fields for both tables. I have executed it locally and it takes almost a minute to return data.

Comment: Of course it doesn't list all the data for all the tables. It lists ngr_titles that have an entry in ngr_monitordata. It also filters ngr_monitordata by the most recent post date (when_posted field). If you want all records from ngr_titles, regardless if they have corresponding row(s) in ngr_monitordata - use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Also, add EXPLAIN before SELECT, run it and post what it says.

Comment: EXPLAIN shows 3 row with the following data: ROW 1: id->1, select_type->PRIMARY, table->t, type->ALL, possible_keys->NULL, key->NULL, key_len->NULL, ref->NULL, rows->242, extra->"". ROW 2: id->1, select_type->PRIMARY, table->m, type->ref, possible_keys->whowhenidx,whenidx,titleidx, key->whenidx, key_len->5, ref->func, rows->4, extra->"". ROW 3: id->2, select_type->DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, table->ngr_monitordata, type->ref, possible_keys->whowhenidx,titleidx, key->titleidx, key_len->5, ref->nocgraph.t.id, rows->26588, extra->"Using where".

Comment: What I'd do is add column `monitordata_id` to ngr_titles table. That column would be a key pointing to `id` of ngr_monitordata table. Using that, you can create the fastest possible join of your huge table, and the whole thing would update trough triggers (ON AFTER INSERT trigger on ngr_monitordata table). I'd also change ngr_monitordata to InnoDB and change innodb_buffer_size MySQL variable.

Comment: It worked beautifully. I have tested it with bulk inserts and the delay on the process after adding the trigger is minimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inner queries whenever possible. It will be slow.

```
SELECT ngr_titles.*, MAX(ngr_monitordata.when_posted) as when_posted
    FROM ngr_titles
    LEFT JOIN ngr_monitordata 
    ON ngr_titles.id = ngr_monitordata.titleid 
    GROUP BY ngr_titles.id
```

EDIT: This is only applicable if both the tables are of same size.

Comment: I've never heard the term 'inner queries' before. Did you mean subqueries?

Comment: Ya. Sub-Queries, Nested Queries, Inner Queries. In different DB's it's called in different names. right?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tested your query in a local database (no traffic) and found 2 issues:  
- I need all the fields from both tables.
- Query is executed in 1.5 minutes

Comment: @Hector Pizarro: ohh.. i initially thought both tables are of huge size. but it is not. here only one table is huge size. so even a simple join like me and others said will take more time than your current query. right?

Comment: Yes, the query is simple but the performance is horrible. That's the problem, I need a solution that will not take so much time to execute. In the meanwhile I have solved it using code only.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an index to `ngr_monitordata` for the following columns `(titleid ASC, when_posted DESC)`.

Comment: Carefully reading, you can see in the SHOW CREATE TABLE that an index exists on those keys, and that isn't the reason for the query being slow. It's the full table join of a huge table on yet another huge table without any WHERE condition or proper join condition.